# Invoke-Command powershell trouble

Tags: function, powershell, invoke-command

**Friend's i've got a trouble with this function, it will run on the remote server, but i've got the following output  :**

*Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '& C:\testNunit\dll\'.
At D:\test\Multithread.ps1:65 char:16
+     Invoke-Command <<<<  -ComputerName $serv -ScriptBlock  $command  ([ScriptBlock]::Create("& $OneProject")) -credential $cred 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand*

```
  function Nunit  { 

##Parse connection parameters
$Connection = @{"server" = "..."; "username" = "..."; "password" = "...."}

$serv = $connection.Get_Item("server")
$user = $connection.Get_Item("username")
$pass = $connection.Get_Item("password")

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force

#Create connection credentials object for Invoke-Command
$cred   = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user, $securePassword

$NunitExe = "C:\testNunit\bin\nunit-console.exe"
   $OneProject = "C:\testNunit\dll\Foundation.Tests.dll"
$TestProjects = "C:\testNunit\dll\"
foreach( $OneProject in ( $TestProjects))
{
 $WorkingDir = "c:\testNunit"
 $NUnitOutput = "c:\testNunit" + $OneProject + ".xml"

 $command = {&"$NunitExe" "$WorkingDir\$OneProject" \noshadow/framework:"net-3.5" /xml:$NUnitOutput}

 }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serv -ScriptBlock  $command  ([ScriptBlock]::Create("& $OneProject")) -credential $cred 

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

After the -Scriptblock parameter you are specifying two scriptblocks - one in $command and one via Create. There should only be one value provided to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues. First, you need to pass in one parameter to the the script block, you essentially have two. Secondly, you need to pass in your variables as arguments in `-ArgumentList`, otherwise, the scriptblock won't recognize them.

Try this:

```
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serv -ScriptBlock  {
     $command = args[0]
     $OneProject = args[1]
 $command & $OneProject} -ArgumentList @($command, $OneProject) -credential $cred
```

Comment: Much thank's for you friends, but your piece of code doesn't work because of Unexpected token here ([ScriptBlock]::Create("& $OneProject"))